# Как инициализировать значения класса, который находится в другом классе?

Tags: c++, ооп

У меня есть класс Node, в котором есть 3 значения. Этот класс является членом класса Contacts. Как мне сделать конструктор в классе Contacts что бы инициализировать значения класса Node. Не передачей члена класса Note в конструктор, а именно значениями.

```
class Node//Класс узла
{
private:
    NOTE data; // Поле данных, содержащее данные типа NOTE
    Node* next; // Указатель на следующий элемент
    Node* prev; // Указатель на предыдущий элемент
public:
    Node(NOTE data, Node* pNext = nullptr, Node* pPrev = nullptr) // конструктор ноды присваивание значения и адреса
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = pNext;
        this->prev = pPrev;
    };
};
```

Этот класс является членом другого класса

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class NOTE
{
private:
    string name;//Имя Фамилия
    string phone;//Номер телефона
    string birthday;//Дата рождения
public:
    NOTE();//Конструктор по умолчанию
    NOTE(string n, string p, string b);//Конструктор 
    string GetName();//Получение значения имени
    string GetPhone();//Получение значения номера телефона
    string GetBirthdat();//Получение значения дня рождения
    void SetName(string n);//Установка Имени
    void SetPhone(string p);//Установка номера телефона
    void SetBirthday(string b);//Установка Дня Рождения
};
```

Comment: А где код класса Contacts?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru изменил

Comment: Что значит класс является членом другого класса? Хотите сказать вложен в другой класс или его объект является членом другого класса?

Comment: Так где класс `Contacts`??

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам помог один из двух ответов, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса не совсем понял как устроен класс `Contacts` но допустим так:

```
class Contacts
{
private:
    NOTE data; 
// ... еще что-то ...    
};
```

Конструктор класса `Contacts` тогда должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
Contacts::Contacts(const string& name, const string& phone, const string& birthday):
     data(name, phone, birthday)
{
   //... работаем с другими полями ...
}
```

Но полагаю класс `Contacts` должен содержать в себе много записей типа `NOTE`, следовательно нужно передавать в конструктор `Contacts` не одну, а несколько наборов полей. Можно сделать это так:

Создать дополнительно структуру например `Data`

```
 struct Data
 {
     const string name;
     const string phone;
     const string birthday;
 }
```

Которая будет  служить только для передачи данных в конструктор (можно объявить эту структуру рядом с `Contacts`):

```
class Contacts
{
private:
    std::list<NOTE> data; //Теперь не одна запись 
// ... еще что-то ...    
};


Contacts::Contacts(const std::list<Data>& a_data):
{
   //Или как-то подругому вставлять если вы не со списком работаете
   for (auto d: a_data)
        data.push_back(NOTE(d.name, d.phone, d.birthday));

   //... работаем с другими полями ...
}
```

Или можно [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) использовать вместо вспомогательной структуры `Data`

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю ваш класс `Contacts` имеет примерно такое поле:

```
Node* contacts;
```

И как я понял вы хотите вместо примерно такой записи:

```
Contacts(Node* contact)
```

Вот такую:

```
Contacts(string name, string phone, string birthday)
```

То есть вместо конструктора инициализации, вы хотите как бы раскрыть структуру `Node`, а в последствие и `Note`. Т.к. это конструктор, то `next` и `prev` никуда не будут указывать и их можно не требовать для передачи, так что раскрываем саму структуру `Note` где у вас 3 поля типа `string`.

Ну и сам конструктор:

```
Contacts(string name, string phone, strng birthday) {
    contacts = new Node({ name, phone, birthday });
}
```

Ну а так дальше можно гадать, что у вас там в классе `Contacts`